# Match repeated words

Tags: php, regex

I want to match repeated words like `abc abc`. Here is the regex:

```
(\w+)(\s\1)+
```

This works great for strings like:

```
pds dd dd dd dd sd
```

and matches `dd dd dd dd` as a group and `"dd"`, `" dd"` but this is not what I am looking for.

I would like to match `dd` seperately just like a split statement which splits around `" "` and returns 4 `dd`. I am not looking for any other methods except a single regex. This can be done using two regex but I am wondering if it is possible to write in a single regex?

Comment: From each match, you can get the Group 1 and Group 2 contents as shown: [`(\w+)\s+(\1)\K`](https://regex101.com/r/F7WG8B/2)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using this regex:

```
(\w+)(?(?=\s+\1\s+\1)|\s+\K(\1))
```

It does not need an explanation because the regex is much clearly explained at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kHex9g/1/).

`(?something|anotherthing)` looks like an `if else` statement. If `something` is present then match it else try to find `anotherthing`.

In above regex, `TRUE` is `null` and hence the regex works.

Here is another regex written by [revo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo) which does not capture multiple groups:

```
(?|\b(\w+)(?= +\1\b) +|\G(?!^)(\w+))
```

[Second regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/8Mw9tK/3)

Comment: So you were OK with multiple capturing groups?

Comment: @revo It's one beautiful regex. Nice work :) Love it.

Comment: I made it just a bit shorter.

Answer (score -1):

Convert the string to array by explode() in with space.

Find number of values repeated by array_count_values()

```
<?php 
$str = 'pds dd dd dd dd sd';
$arr = explode(' ', $str);
$countValues = array_count_values($arr);
if (! empty($countValues)) {
 foreach ($countValues as $countKey => $countValue) {
  if ($countValue > 1) {
   echo "<br/>" . $countKey . ' is repeated ' . $countValue . ' times';
  }
 }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($countValues);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
dd is repeated 4 times

Array
(
    [pds] => 1
    [dd] => 4
    [sd] => 1
)
```

Comment: *I am not looking for any other methods except a single regex.*